# Why doesn't Spring support the order of annotations advice at the method level?

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

```
@Component
@Aspect
@Slf4j(topic = "e")
public class NotVeryUsefulAspect{

    @Pointcut("within(com.lc.aop.for_source.service.impl.AAopServiceImpl)")
    public void pointCutWithinAAopService(){
    }

    @Pointcut("@within(com.lc.aop.for_source.service.XAnnotation)")
    public void pointCutAnnotation(){

    }

    @Before("pointCutWithinAAopService()")
    @Order(0)
    public void adviceBeforeAAopService(){
        log.debug("=======before aop service========");
    }

    @Before("pointCutAnnotation()")
    @Order(-1)
    public void adviceBeforeAAopService2(){
        log.debug("=======before aop annotation========");
    }
}
```

```
@Slf4j(topic = "e")
@Component("a")
@XAnnotation
public class AAopServiceImpl implements AopService {
    @Override
    public void m() {
        log.debug("a -AAopServiceImpl");
    }
}
```

Based on the [advice-ordering](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering)

> Consider collapsing such advice methods into one advice method per join point in each @Aspect class or refactor the pieces of advice into separate @Aspect classes that you can order at the aspect level via Ordered or @Order.

Do I understand correctly that the `@Order` does not work in this case? Why not suport the method level order?

I think this is a very simple function, but it can avoid some unnecessary misunderstandings about `@Order`

I would like to order advice by method level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer to your question is in the [sentence directly before](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering) the one you quoted, in the very same paragraph of the very same info box:

> When two pieces of the same type of advice (for example, two `@After` advice methods) defined in the same `@Aspect` class both need to run at the same join point, the ordering is undefined **(since there is no way to retrieve the source code declaration order through reflection for javac-compiled classes).**

Answer (score 0):

That question should probably be posed to the chaps working on the springframework, that project is located at: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework.

What you're asking for makes sense, but keep in mind that `Order` is meant to prioritize the loading of beans from the context, so it makes sense that `Order` needs to be applied to the `Aspect` and not the `Pointcut` itself.